# How to easy understand the flexbox columns concept (guide)

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, flexbox

Since i've been messing around with flexbox for a while now and finally "have seen the light", i thought i would share my example to show how easy it is to accomplish flexible column layouts with no css hacks with lots of margins, paddings and such..

I am aware that some don't like flexbox at all and probably have a good reason for that, but this post is for those who want to know what it is, and get a working and usable example which is really, really easy to understand at first sight...

First some HTML:

```
<div class="header">100 setup</div>
   <div class="flexcontainer">
   <div class="flexbox flex100">100</div>
</div>

<div class="header">75/25 setup</div>
<div class="flexcontainer">
   <div class="flexbox flex75">75</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex25">25</div>
</div>

<div class="header">50/50 setup</div>
<div class="flexcontainer">
   <div class="flexbox flex50">50</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex50">50</div>
</div>

<div class="header">33/33/33 setup</div>
<div class="flexcontainer">
   <div class="flexbox flex33">33</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex33">33</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex33">33</div>
</div>

<div class="header">20/20/20/20 setup</div>
<div class="flexcontainer">
   <div class="flexbox flex20">20</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex20">20</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex20">20</div>
   <div class="flexbox flex20">20</div>
</div>
```

Then some CSS :

```
.flexcontainer {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
   border:1px solid #3B3B3B;
   background-color: #919191;
   width:100%;
   min-height:100px;
}
.flexbox {
   margin:5px;
   border:1px solid #F2F2F2;
   background-color:#E3E3E3;
   padding:5px;
}
.header {
   font-size:0.75em;
   font-family:verdana;
   width:100%;
   display:block;
   line-height:20px;
}
.flex20 {
   -webkit-flex: 4 0 0;
   flex: 4 0 0;
}
.flex25 {
   -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
   flex: 1 0 0;
}
.flex33 {
   -webkit-flex:3 0 0;
   flex: 3 0 0;
}
.flex50 {
   -webkit-flex:1 0 0;
   flex: 1 0 0;
}
.flex75 {
   -webkit-flex: 2 0 0;
   flex: 2 0 0;
}
.flex100 {
   -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
   flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5f66ums/5/) for viewing and testing it out

Comment: This is awesome! I had never seen that before, but I'm sure going to use now. Cheers man!

Comment: U're welcome :) happy coding!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: This would be better structured as a Q&A answered by your good self. +1ed though, because this helped me so much when searching this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Started using the flex property a few weeks ago, and I've used it excessively on the past 3 websites I've built. Working at an agency that swears by completely responsive websites, the flex property has been a very easy to use tool.

might be also worth mentioning that other browsers require a prefix like -webkit- as you've shown

```
display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box;/* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works)*/
display: -ms-flexbox;/* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex;/* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

Comment: Yes... Thats important. Especially Internet Explorer, even the never versions are quite a mess without the browser spesific css..